# How can I find a decent synth teacher in London

Tags: keyboard, synthesizer, teaching, teachers

I've been searching online and most of the sites I've found only seem to have piano teachers but I want someone who can also help with the sound editing / technical aspects of my new synth. Have managed to work a lot of it out myself but could really do with a few lessons with someone decent. Any thoughts or pointers massively appreciated! :-D

Comment: What a pity I'm not decent!  :-)  But I am in London.   What do you need to know?  I can't think of much synth-specific stuff that wouldn't be just assisting you in exploring the manual.

Comment: Also try http://superprof.co.uk

Answer (score 2):

Here are some suggestions:

- Call a piano teacher and ask if they teach this or can recommend someone
- Call/text/email someone you know that plays synth. Tell them that you want to learn how, and ask for them to recommend someone. Maybe they will even offer to show you some stuff.
- Call a local music store (maybe even the one where you bought yours) and ask if they have anyone that teaches this stuff or can recommend someone. Better yet, go down to the store and talk to the salesperson in the synth section, they may be willing to give you a few lessons or at least know someone.
- If there is a place where you often see piano teachers advertised, check those places to see if anyone lists this as something they teach.
- Check with a local community college and see if anyone in the music department can recommend someone. Maybe even a high school teacher would be able to recommend someone.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend online tutorials such as [this one.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E341VKfaBmU) Most synthesizers, hardware or software, function in the same way and provide the same core components (oscillators, filters, envelopes, etc.)